# Magento 2 : How to add Js and CSS using php in a page in frontend?

Tags: javascript, css, magento2.2

In Magento 2, How to add Js and CSS using php in a page in frontend ? What are the php methods in magento 2 for adding css and js in a page object?

Comment: Please be more specific or explain a bit more

Comment: - For adding CSS have a look of this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html).
- For adding JS have a look of this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Using Simple Layouts**
In this method you can add the `CSS/JS` files in frontend using layout files only.
1. Open the layout file present at: `Webspeaks/Test/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`
Adding layout in `default.xml` will be available on almost all pages of your agento 2 site. You can also add this code to any particluar page using the following layout file:

```
Webspeaks/Test/view/frontend/layout/<frontName>_<controllerName>_<actionName>.xml


<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Webspeaks_Fancyfeedback/css/my_css.css"/>
        <link src="Webspeaks_Fancyfeedback/js/my_js.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

2 Now create the css and js files at following locations:

```
Webspeaks/Test/view/frontend/web/js/my_js.js

Webspeaks/Test/view/frontend/web/css/my_css.css
```

Now clear the cache using following command:

```
php bin/magento cache:clear
```

**Method 2: Using Blocks** 
Now change the code of layout file as follows:

For this you can CSS/JS files by adding a block in the head block of Magento 2.
1.In your layout file add following code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
        <block  template="head.phtml"
                class="Webspeaks\Fancyfeedback\Block\Head"
                name="webspeaks_fancyfeedback_block_head" />
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Now create the `Head.php` block class in your module: `Webspeaks/Test/Block/Head.php`

```
namespace Webspeaks\Fancyfeedback\Block;
class Head extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public $assetRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, 
        array $data = [],    
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepository
    )
    {
        // Get the asset repository to get URL of our assets
        $this->assetRepository = $assetRepository;
        return parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

You can see in step 1 we have specified the template file for our block. Now we will create the template file at: `Webspeaks/Test/view/frontend/templates/head.phtml`

```
<?php
    $asset_repository = $this->assetRepository;
    $js_asset = $asset_repository->createAsset('Webspeaks_Fancyfeedback/js/ws_ff.js');
    $css_asset = $asset_repository->createAsset('Webspeaks_Fancyfeedback/css/ws_ff.css');
?>
<link href="<?php echo $css_asset->getUrl(); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<?php echo $js_asset->getUrl(); ?>"></script>
```

Again clear the cache and you are done.