# Magento 2: How to include custom js file in phtml file

Tags: magento2

How to include js file in phtml file.

eg:

```
if(some text){
 add js file here.....
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you like to do that? Can't you include your file via xml ? Anyway... answering your questions: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213402/magento-2-how-to-add-js-and-css-using-php-in-a-page-in-frontend?rq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to add js in phtml is via **requirejs**

## Theme solution :

Supposing that your js file is: `myfile.js`

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/myfile'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/myfile.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert("Yes, got it.");
       }
});
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/{yourfile}.phtml**

```
<?php if(condition here): ?>
    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
            myscript();
        });
    </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

---

## Module solution :

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'Vendor_module/js/myfile',
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/myfile.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert("Yes, got it.");
       }
});
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/{yourfile}.phtml**

```
<?php if(condition here): ?>
    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
            myscript();
        });
    </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

**Info:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: How to add requirejs-config.js in custom module?

Comment: look my update.

Comment: Thanks..Let me check

Comment: I don't want to make function in js file. need to call in document ready

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Theme/js/customjs" : {
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is my way to add JS in any .phtml. Add this at the end of phtml to call particular JS.

Comment: I like this solution as it uses the Magento framework standards - following their methods for adding external scripts in a CSP friendly method.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to write the script for a particular page with the condition than write down the script into phtml based on your condition.

**Like this way !!!**

```
<?php
if (condition) { ?>
    <script>
    require(['jquery','domReady!'], function ($) {
        //write down the script
    }); 
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

**Secound Method**

```
<?php if (condition) { ?>
    <script src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Catalog::js/script.js')?>"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I did the same. My js code is too big. so i need to create seperate js for this and call on the same place.

Comment: I have added the second method please check and implement.

Answer (score 0):

You'll call js using the below code in .phtml file if your condition is fulfilled.

Add the below code in your .phtml file.

```
<?php if(condition): ?>
<div id="div-ko-example" data-bind="scope:'div-ko-example'">
     <h2 data-bind="text: message"></h2>
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
           "components": {
                "div-ko-example": {
                    "component": "Vendor_Modulename/js/ko_template"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also, create js file name with **ko_template.js** at **app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/ko_template.js**
And write code as per your need. See the below code for your reference.

```
define(['ko'], function(ko) {
    return function(config) {
        this.message = ko.observable(config.exampleMessage);
    }
});
```

> **Please Note:** it's not an exact code as per your requirement. I just
>   give you a reference that you'll fulfill your requirement by call js
>   using knockout like above example.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you please describe more  your answer?

Comment: @Shomita I have updated my answer just for your understanding. Please check.