# Add a script to a template file

Tags: template

This is the default `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml`

This layout defines between other things :

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="checkout.success" template="Magento_Checkout::success.phtml" cacheable="false">
    <container name="order.success.additional.info" label="Order Success Additional Info"/>
</block>
```

What I would like to do is add a piece of script like a simple:

```
<script>
    console.log('script added');
</script>
```

To the success.phtml template file.

What is the best way to do it ?

Notice that I already have a custom `design/frontend/folder/Magento_Checkout/templates` but success isn't in here. I guess I can add a custom `success.phtml` in this location, but I probably need to specify the new file somewhere ?

Comment: This should help you get started: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301627/magento-2-how-to-include-custom-js-file-in-phtml-file

As for success.phtml not being in templates, that is normal and requires you create the files you want to overwrite. I normally copy the existing file to my theme and then make changes as required. You won't need to reference it as long it is named the same and found in the same folder structure as the file you are overriding.

Answer (score 0):

I recently added snippet of code to success page

https://github.com/DominicWatts/GoogleEcommerceTracking

Check the block logic, frontend layout and phtml